# Allowing multiple executables into a "Run only specified applications" group policy at one time

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, powershell

At my workplace we whitelist executables using a "Run only specified Windows applications" group policy applied to the domain. At certain times we need to whitelist large number of executables at a time (say with printers or scanners). Through the GUI you can only add one executable at a time, is there an alternative way to add multiple executables in at once? I looked at powershell group policy commands and that looked like a dead end.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you had a look through the policy folder - you may get lucky and find they're in plain text somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Well, the old rule of thumb is every GPO is typically a registry setting somewhere. You might want to take a look here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461027.aspx

Start with the `Set-GPRegistryValue` section. Looks like this would be the primary way to modify GPOs via PowerShell. You could start with a GPO that has some of these software restrictions and then use the `Get-GPRegistryValue` cmdlets to the basic setup for a software restriction and then just write a script that adds more to it when needed. I've never used these specific cmdlets but I've used the GPO module many times to do many things and it is fairly decent. I may look into it further some time and let you know.

Keep in mind that GPOs are stored in two places, on SYSVOL and there is an AD object. There is versioning in place and it is not recommend that you modify configuration files directly (obviously uploading scripts and msi files for software installs is a different matter).